# Chai with promises is not waiting for previous promises to be resolved

Tags: protractor, chai

I have below function and I am using it in expect.

```
 function Create() {
    var that = this;
    // Goto home page of App.
    // Async call
    that.homePage();
    // Async call
    Utils.click(projectsSelectors.project_create, false, that.browser);
    // Async call
    Utils.elementIsVisible(stock_avatar, that.browser);
    // Async call
    Utils.fill(name_input, that.name, that.browser);
    // Async call
    stockAvatar.call(that);
    // Async call
    Utils.click(create_save, false, that.browser);
    // Verify if it's created.
    // Async call
    return that.$is_Created();
 }
```

But when I use like below

```
expect(Create()).to.eventually.equal(true);
```

The expectation is just passed without doing anything. The above Create method contains multiple asynchronous calls.

I even chained all the calls inside Create method, but still, the expectation is just passing without doing anything on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your test method must [return the promise](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/)

```
it("should do something", function()
{
    return expect(Create()).to.eventually.equal(true);
}
```